Is Using Resistors Justifiable in Impedance Matching Circuits for High-Power Broadband Acoustic Transducers Despite Power Loss?
I'm designing a high-power(~1kV) broadband transmitting system using a piezoelectric ceramic transducer for an acoustic transducer. In my research, most papers utilize only LC (inductor and capacitor) networks for impedance matching, describing the matching circuits as lossless (reactive) elements. However, these studies do not explicitly prohibit the use of resistors in the matching process.
Circuit Structure: I am using electrically coupled resonant RLC tanks in my impedance matching circuit.
Main Questions:

Can resistors be effectively incorporated alongside inductors and capacitors in impedance-matching circuit designs for high-power broadband acoustic transducers to achieve maximum power factor, or should resistors be avoided due to the associated power dissipation and energy losses?
Is it still advisable to avoid using resistors in the matching circuit even if they are used in combination with L and C components?

What I've Considered:
Incorporating resistors could help stabilize the circuit and achieve a better power factor. However, the resultant power loss and heat generation are significant concerns, especially in high-power applications. I'm seeking guidance on whether the trade-offs make resistor inclusion worthwhile or if alternative methods (Only using reactive elements) should be preferred for impedance matching in this context.

It makes no sense to use resistors unless you are happy to throw away 50% of the power (in effect the same as running at a power factor of 0.5). Matching with L and C is so easy, I just can't imagine a numerical situation where it won't win every time over resistive matching. But, you haven't revealed anything numerical so, it's impossible to make a judgement.
Of course, the other option is to use a wide bandwidth impedance converter based around a step up transformer. Yes, there is cost but, if you want top performance at lowest loss then, it's highly likely to be the best option.

Thank you all for your insightful responses, and I apologize for not providing clear details about my circuit initially. To clarify, I am using resistors in combination with inductors and capacitors in an electrically coupled RLC resonant tank for impedance matching. Of course, this circuit includes resistors which cause power loss. I'm designing a broadband matching circuit in the low-frequency range, and matching with only LC components is difficult, so I'm using resistors. However, since this causes power dissipation, I am considering whether to explore entirely different circuit structures

Well, if you need a high impedance matching ratio then using L and C will limit the bandwidth so, maybe if you use a transformer to take up much of the slack in terms of impedance ratio, you'll find that the Q of the resulting LC is lower and the bandwidth is wider. I don't think you strictly mean broadband (rather you mean wide-band) @kth

Thank you for your recommendation; "wideband" is the correct term. Initially, I intended to design the matching circuit using a doubly tuned transformer structure. In the referenced paper, "Doubly-Tuned Transformer Networks: A Tutorial", resistors are incorporated alongside transformers in the circuit design. Therefore, I am curious whether using resistors in the matching circuit is acceptable when adopting this structure.

I don't have access to that paper. Regarding this site usage, it is in this site's interest and yours to raise a new post if you want to ask about a specific variant of impedance matching. In raising a new post you open the question up to the whole floor and, you can raise a comment here to attract my attention to it @kth

I sincerely appreciate the valuable feedback and the insights I've gained from your comments. Based on your suggestions, I have reopened my post. Your support has been beneficial! New post

You need to define what's important to your application.
If power efficiency, then resistors are always bad. The 'cost' of that may be a poor flatness specification over a wide frequency range. You may be able to pre-emphasise the drive to compensate, but the system will always be sensitive to a shift in transducer parameters when it's changed, or the temperature is changed, or the load is changed.
If you want a flat frequency response over a wide bandwidth, resistors may be useful, and the cost is burning power. Any loss will tend to reduce the sensitivity of the system to parameter changes.
You get what you pay for, and you try to arrange the compromise to be attractive to your end users.

Thank you for your comment. My primary goal is to design a matching circuit that cancels the significant reactive components of the transmitting transducer. Although the frequency response flatness has already been achieved based on the sensor's characteristics, the remaining challenge is to optimize the power efficiency for the end user.
